# access wrapped value, return object, iterator or yield?

Tags: python, list, iterator, generator

I have a class `ADT`, which has a list in it. I want to wrap the data by accessing the data through a function. I have come up with the following ways to access the data. *I just want to know the difference between those ways, and which one should I pick up.*

```
class ADT(object):
    """The comments is a possible replace in the feture
    """
    def __init__(self)
        #... other data...
        self.adt = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        #self.adt = {1:2, 3:4}


    #... other logic...

    def datas1(self):
        return self.adt
        #return self.adt.items()

    def datas2(self):
        return iter(self.adt)
        #return iter(self.adt.items())

    def datas3(self):
        for i in self.adt:
            yield i
        #for i in self.adt.items():
        #   yield i
```

Use case

```
l = ADT()
for i in l.datas(): #use datas1 or datas2 or datas3 as datas
    #do something
```

Comment: It basically depends on what you are trying to do with the `datas()` function, is there any other kind of processing that it has to do? Or it simply returns the list? If its just returning the list, why not directly use `l.lst` ?

Comment: This is just part of my real situation. Maybe some day I would replace the `list` with some other kind of  data type. So I use a `datas` as a interface to access the data, just to guarantee the data may be access in the `for i in l.data()` way.

Comment: As Anand said, it depends on what you're doing.  Creating a wrapper which reproduces already existent functionality for it now because you *might* do something different with it later in the future is silly.  If anything, create a new class that extends list with the functionality that you want, and replace self.lst with that object type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me attempt to improve your question and then answer it. The only case where it makes sense to provide a wrapper is if you have a potentially [large and lazy](http://swizec.com/blog/python-and-lazy-evaluation/swizec/5148) sequence to begin with:

```
class ADT(object):
    def __init__(self, count):
        # Count could be very large. Or maybe you want to perform a function 
        # on each value before passing it to adt, e.g.,
        # self.adt = (expensive_func(x) for x in xrange(count))  
        self.adt = xrange(count)  
        self.adt_as_list = list(self.adt)
        self.adt_as_iter = iter(self.adt)

    @property
    def adt_as_gen(self):
        for x in self.adt:
            y = yield
            yield x + y
```

In this case, your choice depends on the use case.

**1. The data can fit in memory**. Use the list.

```
l = ADT(10)
data = l.adt_as_list
data
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**2. The data can't fit in memory but you just want to loop**. Use the attribute directly.

```
l = ADT(10000)
data = l.adt
func = lambda x: x + 1
(func(x) for x in l.adt).next()
>>> 1
```

**2. The data can't fit in memory and you just need the next value**. Use the iterator.

```
l = ADT(10000)
data = l.adt_as_iter
data.next()
>>> 0
```

**2. You want to use a [coroutine](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/)**. Use the generator.

```
l = ADT(10000)
data = l.adt_as_gen
data.next()
data.send(2)
>>> 2
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your answer and edit attempt. It makes everything much more clear. One thing need to take into concern is the data interface to the user. Is it possible to use one common interface to use anyone of the implementation?

Comment: @luoluo If you know the exact circumstance under which the user will want to access the data, you can provide a wrapper like so:

`def data(self, case): return {'iter': self.adt_as_iter...}[case]`

usage: `data = l.data('iter')`

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is to wrap the data in a class, user only knows about the interface say `data()`. The interface supports `for i in adt.data()` operation. So In this case, does this mean update the `data()` interface according to the data type used. The only thing need to care is the `data()` return something iterable?

Comment: I think we are on the same page... as defined, `data` is a method. You would call `adt = ADT(10000)` and then `for i in adt.data('iter')` You can't avoid having to provide an argument to the `data` method, so that it knows which data structure to return `iter, list...`.

Comment: You can also modify `data` so by default it returns a specific type. i.e., `def data(self, case='list')`. Now, either `adt.data('list')` or `adt.data()` would return a list.

Comment: Yes.  At anytime, there is only one kind of data type needed in the warpper class. No need to use another parameter for `data()`. In short, do you mean use different kinds of return form based on different kinds of data type used? Any updated the `data()` interface's implementation according to the data type used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92461/discussion-between-reubano-and-luoluo).

Answer (score 0):

As is, your list, in it's entirety, is already in memory, because you've set it up and defined all of it's entities.

- `datas1()` will just a reference to the `self.lst` list object
- `datas2()` will return an iterator object
- `datas3()` will return a generator object

For more information on what each one is, read up on the documentation (as "Explain what a generator and an iterator are" is off topic).

If you don't have any extra functionality planned, you have no reason to implement this because of a future case of when it might be.  You're overprogramming for unknowns.  If at a later time, you want `lst` to act differently, or add functionality onto it, you have the option of extending the list class to handle that.  There's no reason to rewrite and rewrap functionality that's already there.